# How to boot Linux from image on disk or "Poor Man's Install"?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

Is it possible to boot Linux with user space applications from file/image on disk?

I can copy content of any live image (for example from http://www.debian.org/CD/live/) to separate partition with any FS supported by **grub** and boot from it.

But how about booting from file instead of partition?

During searching I found that users name this as "*Poor Man's Install*" but most of them use partitions instead of single file....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to boot Fedora Live CD iso from a Hard Drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/210333/how-to-boot-fedora-live-cd-iso-from-a-hard-drive)

Comment: [Is there a Linux equivalent for VHD from which it can boot?](https://superuser.com/q/654207/241386)

Answer (score 1):

[MEMDISK](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK) will allow you to boot from a disk image.