# Is there a Linux equivalent for VHD from which it can boot?

Tags: linux, vhd, disk-image, virtual-disk, boot-to-vhd

I have searched for this quite a lot, yet all I could find was *VLite*. By the way, I'm talking about an equivalent for Windows native VHD boot and not virtualization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Grub](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) can map pretty much any disk image files and boot from that

- [grub4dos](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/map.htm) and grub1 support the `map` command for booting from **read-only images**. I'm not sure about their capabilities to boot read-write images. There are 2 types of mapping

  - ***Memory map:*** The image is *loaded onto memory* before mapping as disk, usually used with floppy disk images. When memory mapping is used the disk image file can be non-contiguous. For example:

    ```
    map (hd0,0)/win98.ima (fd0)
    ```
  - ***Direct map:*** map the file using *int13*, requires the file to be contiguous

    ```
    map (device)/path/file.iso (hd32)
    ```

    After all mappings were done you'll need to commit them with `map --hook`

    These types of mapping allow you to easily boot any live Linux distros. If necessary you can use a [casper rw persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2566121/995714) disk image for **non-volatile data**. For more information read [LiveCD/Persistence](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence)
- In `grub2` you'll have to use the [`loopback`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/loopback.html#loopback) command which can be used to boot both read-only and **read-write images**

  > ## [5.2 Loopback booting](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Loopback-booting.html)
  >
  > GRUB is able to read from an image (be it one of CD or HDD) stored on any of its accessible storages (refer to see [loopback](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/loopback.html#loopback) command). However the OS itself should be able to find its root.
  >
  > This usually involves running a userspace program running before the real root is discovered. This is achieved by GRUB loading a specially made small image and passing it as ramdisk to the kernel. This is achieved by commands `kfreebsd_module`, `knetbsd_module_elf`, `kopenbsd_ramdisk`, `initrd` (see [initrd](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/initrd.html#initrd)), `initrd16` (see [initrd](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/initrd.html#initrd)), `multiboot_module`, `multiboot2_module` or `xnu_ramdisk` depending on the loader.

In the past [wubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(software)) used the same technique to boot Ubuntu from an image without an ext4 root partition

---

If you're using syslinux then there's an equivalent feature called [MEMDISK](https://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=MEMDISK)

> MEMDISK is meant to allow booting legacy operating systems. MEMDISK can boot floppy images, hard disk images and some ISO images.
>
> MEMDISK simulates a disk by claiming a chunk of high memory for the disk and a (very small - typically, 2K) chunk of low (DOS) memory for the driver itself, then hooking the INT 13h (disk driver) and INT 15h (memory query) BIOS interrupts.

See

- [Booting an EXT4 image file from GRUB2](https://superuser.com/q/412028/241386)
- [grub: boot from ISO](https://superuser.com/q/154133/241386)
- [How to boot Fedora Live CD iso from a Hard Drive?](https://superuser.com/q/210333/241386)
- [How to boot Linux from image on disk or "Poor Man's Install"?](https://superuser.com/q/597662/241386)
- [Can I boot Linux from a VHD?](https://superuser.com/q/33535/241386)
- [Install Ubuntu from ISO image directly from hard disk of a system running Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/q/340156/253474)
- [Deploy Linux into, and boot from, VHD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/309900/44425)
- [How to Boot Linux ISO Images Directly From Your Hard Drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/)
- [Is it possible to native boot Linux from raw disk image?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1004327/253474)
- [booting linux from a loop file system](http://www.opopop.net/booting_linux_from_a_loop_file_system/)

Comment: I thought so - might help to add some information on the specifics on how to do that - for posterity's sake.